# How to access a variable using a string in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I receive in input a string that should be the name of an array. How do I call the array as a variable and not a string?

```
 <div onclick="smt(this.id)" id="name"></div>

<script>

name=[...]

function smt(id){
?
}
```

Comment: Just rename the variable, `name` is a type protected property of `window`.

Comment: Either using `eval`, or easier and safer, `window["name"]` if it's a global variable.

Comment: you should just avoid doing this, make `name` an object to hold things, i.e `data = {name:...}`, then simply do `data[id]`, debugging a container var would be a whole lot simpler then tracking what you put in window

Comment: Your question seems a bit unclear, but I think you'll want to use window[id] inside of that function to get the value of the variable `name`, assuming `name` is a global variable and `id="name"`

Comment: What you're trying to do is common in some languages, but it is definitely not idiosyncratic in JavaScript. You can make an object that holds values useful to your event handlers (or whatever), or instead use `data-` attributes on your HTML elements themselves for values to be used by code.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name